# Using NSString to call a function in XCode 4.x

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I'm sure this is a simple question, but how can I call a function with [self MyFunction]; where 'MyFunction' is a NSString? I want to call functions using various variables which, when joined, form the function name (ie. FunctionName1, FunctionName2, etc.)

For example (simplified):

```
NSString *MyStringValue=@"FunctionName";
int MyNumber = 1;
NSString *MyFunction=[myStringValue stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d ",myNumber];
```

So I'm looking to call the function "FunctionName1" using:

```
[self MyFunction];
```

but that doesn't work. Can anyone help?

---

EDIT: Here's the full code that now works:

```
-(void)getnewblock {

    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSNumber *actionblockload = nil;
    actionblockload = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"actionblock"];
    int actionblock = [actionblockload intValue];

    NSString *block=@"setblock";
    NSString *blockanimate=@"blockanimate";

    NSString *blocktochange=[block stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",actionblock];
    NSString *blocktoanimate=[blockanimate stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",actionblock];

    SEL sel1 = NSSelectorFromString(blocktochange);
    SEL sel2 = NSSelectorFromString(blocktoanimate);

    [self performSelector:sel1];
    [self performSelector:sel2];

    [self setblockimages];
}
```

The only thing is I get the 'may cause a leak' message - although the app runs fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow Mark.

In Cocoa Touch, what you refer to as a "function" is called "selector" (a method that has both a signature and a target) and has its own type `SEL`. In order to achieve what you want you need to first get the selector by name and then perform it. Here is some code to get you started:

```
-(void) yourMainMethod{

   NSString * methodName = @"calculateAcceleration";
   SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);

   [self performSelector:sel];

}

-(void)calculateAcceleration
{
   NSLog(@"Called!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting a PerformSelector warning (PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown) and the app crashes. Basically I'm trying to avoid 36 If statements to check something so I'm trying to combine the string and integer to create the name of the 'selector' that gets called.

Comment: Well, you have to have a method with that name e.g. `calculateAcceleration` in my case above. Sending random method names will not work. Can you add all the code that does that to your question?

Comment: In other words, you still need to have 32 methods, but you can call them dynamically, with the method name only (string)

Comment: Okay, the rouge space after the '%d' was causing the crash. Still getting the leak error message though? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below

```
SEL function = @selector(testFunction);
[self performSelector:function];
```

-(void)testFunction
{

```
NSLog(@"ABC Test");
```

}

But Not Call NSString via self as function.

thanks

Comment: When I try that 'MyFunction' is flagged as an unused variable (I replaced 'testFunction' with 'MyFunction') and 'PerformSelector' is flagged as a possible leak. The app crashed inevitably.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is not possible to have "NSString" as a method name.

But, you can have conditional checks so as to select a proper method that has to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Nsstring *newNsstring;
int *YourInt;

newNsstring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",yourNsstringName,yourInt,nil];
```

then you can edit only your new `NSString`  but i dont think you can make it ur method's name

Answer (score 0):

If one can

```
NSString *stringMethode = @"MyMethodName"
SEL mySelector = NSSelectorFromString(stringMethode);

if([self respondsToSelector:mySelector]){

    [self performSelector:mySelector withObject:nil];

}else{
    //error not method
}

- (void)MyMethodName
{
    //call methode :)
}
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: what you do not understand?